# Does this function ($\Bbb Z\to\Bbb Z$) ever return a perfect square?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

$$f(x) = 4x^4 + 24x^3 +32x^2 + 12x + 1$$

How would you prove whether or not this function returns perfect squares?

I came across it while trying for a proof that 4 perfect squares are never in arithmetic progression. The line of reasoning was:

Start with a 3-AP: $t_1^2, t_2^2, t_3^2$.

$t_1^2 + t_3^2 = 2t_2^2$

$(t_2 - (t_2 - t_1))^2 + (t_2 + (t_3 - t_2))^2 = 2t_2^2$

$(t_2 - t_1)^2 + (t_3 - t_2)^2 = 2t_2(2t_2 - t_1 - t_3)$

Set $b = t_3 - t_2$ and $k = 2t_2 - t_1 - t_3$.

$(b + k)^2 + b^2 = 2t_2k$

Reducing mod 2k,

$2b^2 + k^2 \equiv 0 \pmod{2k}$

k must be even. Set k = 2j.

$2b^2 + 4j^2 \equiv 0 \pmod{4j}$

$2b^2 \equiv 0 \pmod{4j}$

$b^2 \equiv 0 \pmod{2j}$

Then,

$t_1 = \dfrac{b^2}{2j} - j$

$t_2 = \dfrac{b^2}{2j} + b + j$

$t_3 = \dfrac{b^2}{2j} + 2b + j$

All possible inputs $(b, j)$ where $2j \mid b^2$ cover all perfect square triplets in arithmetic progression.

The fourth term would then be

$t_4^2 = \dfrac{b^4}{4j^2} + \dfrac{3b^3}{j} + 8b^2 + 6bj + j^2$ .

As a simple case, set $b = 2xj$. Then $t_4^2 = j^2(4x^4 + 24x^3 + 32x^2 + 12x + 1)$. Then in this case, $\dfrac{t_4^2}{j^2}$ is equal to the above function, which means that it can't evaluate to a perfect square (for $x \in \mathbb{Z}$).

Comment: If you mean is it ever a perfect square, $f(0)= 1$ is a perfect square. If you mean is it always a perfect square, $f(1)= 73$, which is not a perfect square.

Comment: Also $f(-1)=1$, a perfect square.

Comment: Mordell gives several quartics with only trivial solutions, one of them is $x^4 - x^2 y^2 + y^4  = z^2 $  with $\gcd(x,y) = 1.$ Page 20, formula number (8). He uses this to prove no four squares in arithmetic progression, which is Theorem 3 on page 21. Mordell, Diophantine Equations.  I see, page 19, he says he will consider several $x^4 + k x^2 y^2 + y^4  = z^2, $ with $\gcd(x,y) = 1.$

Comment: @mathematics2x2life Sorry, I should exclude the trivial cases of t1 = t2 (x = -1) and t2 = t3 (x = 0).

Answer (score 3):

The technique of completing the square works fine. So, start by writing
$$4x^4+24x^3+32x^2+12x+1=(2x^2+6x-1)^2+24x$$
and try to place $f(x)$ between two consecutive integer squares.

Comment: Will it ever fall between two consecutive integer squares (excluding x = -1, 0)?

Comment: @pd-ape How did you try to answer this question?

Comment: Ok thanks I get it now.